# 'What' vs 'What is it that'

Tags: grammar, difference, questions

A friend of mine made a question from this statement:

> The guest asks for the key to his room first.
>
> What is it that the guest asks for first?

We can normally say:

> What does the guest ask for first?

I don't know why, but to me, they don't mean exactly the same. But my friend insists that they mean exactly the same and can always be used interchangeably.
I don't know how to explain, but his question sounds more emphatic maybe? Or a question asked out of curiosity?

I wonder if they mean exactly the same to native speakers of English.

Comment: They mean exactly the same.

Comment: They mean exactly the same. :)